# TFS java SDK is leaving file descriptors open

Tags: tfs, msdn, file-descriptor, tfs-sdk

I am using TFS java SDK 12.0 to get work items data from TFS server. At the end of the process when i run lsof command i see lots of file descriptors open for .lock files in the TFS temp cache

Example below is the snapshot of lsof command[image]

Here is how i am creating my workItem Client and closing it.

```
tpc = new TFSTeamProjectCollection(url, createCredentials(user, password));

if (tpc != null) {
    workItemClient = tpc.getWorkItemClient();
}

//closing client 
workItemClient.close();
tpc.close();
```

I have checked and confirmed that workItemClient.close() is getting executed.
Can any body tell why these descriptors are left open or how to close them.

Comment: Check if there is a method similar as `clients.clear()`, just reference the [TFSConnection.java](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/blob/master/source/com.microsoft.tfs.core/src/com/microsoft/tfs/core/TFSConnection.java) sample to check if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's fixed there, but are you able to upgrade to the latest SDK?
https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases

Comment: Tried with JDK 14 but the issue still persist. On further investigation i found that this is the issue with multi threading. when I create multi client instances to execute in  parallel, then this problem is seen. with single thread this is not the issue.